# Recursive query replacement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have these 2 queries which returns the same output:

```
;WITH reta
                 AS (SELECT *
                     FROM TEST r
                     WHERE Group_ID = 2
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT t.*
                     FROM TEST t
                          INNER JOIN reta r ON t.Parent_ID = r.Group_ID)
                 SELECT  * 
                 FROM reta order by 1;
```

AND

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST t
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST t1 ON t.Parent_ID = t1.Group_ID
WHERE t.Group_ID >= 2
ORDER BY 1
```

But If I changed group_ID from 2 to 3 it returns a different result. My above query returns 2 rows but my 2nd query returns 103 rows. I am finding it difficult how to match the output of both the query.

Comment: You can't replicate the functionality of a recursive Common Table Expression by just using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. What you have there is hierarchical data, and the most common way to get a dataset from that type of data is to use an rCTE.

Comment: So there is no way we can avoid recursive CTE to get hierarchical data?

Comment: You could have a look at Jeff Moden's Hierarchies on Steroids articles ([#1](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hierarchies-on-steroids-1-convert-an-adjacency-list-to-nested-sets) & [#2](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hierarchies-on-steroids-2-a-replacement-for-nested-sets-calculations-1)), however, these will create static version of your data; so if you have continually changing data these may not be ideal.

Comment: @RedDevil . . . You can use a `while` loop in a stored procedure or function.